# Recursively Defining a Specific Function

Tags: functions

I have to define a function that yields $1/1^2$, $1/2^2$, $1/3^2$, $1/4^2$, $\ldots$. The function is defined from the positive Naturals to the positive Rationals. I cannot for the life of me think of a function. Please give me a hint. I let $r(0)=1/1^2$. So, I must come up with a function that says F(r(0))=$1/2^2$, $F(F(r(0)))=1/3^2$, and so on.

Comment: @MITjanitor: $\mathbb{R}_+$ is not the positive rationals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Now that the problem has been clarified by the OP:*

The function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\left(1+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}}\right)^2}$$
works, because
$$f\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\frac{1}{\left(1+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{1/n^2}}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{(1+n)^2}$$

Comment: I think the OP wants a recursive definition, which admittedly is not so hard to find from here. :)

Comment: Oh, I put that in wrong. The input would be the last output, i.e., if trying to get 1/3^2, then input would be 1/2^2. So, no.

Comment: @user67581: That doesn't make sense, because the domain of the function is supposed to be positive natural numbers, and $1/2^2$ is certainly not one.

Comment: So, what my book tells me to do, I define r(0)=1/1^2. Now I must input r(0) in a function, i.e. F(r(0)), and so on, F(F(r(0))), and on and on.

Comment: Do you agree, though, that if that is what you are trying to do, then the domain of $F$ cannot be the positive naturals?

Comment: Well, sure, as long as you understand that $1/n^2$ is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want $f(n)=\frac1{n^2}$. If you mean that you need to define the function recursively, do a little algebra:

$$f(n+1)=\frac1{(n+1)^2}=\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\cdot\frac1{n^2}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2f(n)=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^2f(n)\;.$$

Either of the last two expressions gives you a reasonable definition of $f(n+1)$ in terms of $f(n)$. (And the recursion looks even prettier if you express $f(n)$ in terms of $f(n-1)$ instead.)

Of course you must also specify the initial condition, the value of $f(1)$.